# Using COALSCE with 3 JOINS on an SQL Query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT teams.t_id, teams.t_name, teams.t_icon
                (COALESCE((SELECT SUM(matches.m_hteam_score) FROM matches WHERE matches.m_tid = teams.t_id), 0) + 
                    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(matches.m_ateam_score) FROM matches WHERE matches.m_tid2 = teams.t_id), 0)
                ) as totalscore           
            FROM teams
                LEFT JOIN divisions ON divisions.d_id = matches.m_did
                LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.m_did = divisions.d_id
                LEFT JOIN leagues ON leagues.l_id = divisions.d_lid
            WHERE leagues.l_id = ? AND matches.m_finished = ? AND matches.m_did = ?
```

My QUERY gives me the error "teams.t_icon" doesn't exist, even though teams is suppose to resemble the table name and t_icon is the column in the table.

I don't understand how it would not work, but the COALESCE I have in here seems to effect it from allowing the query to run correctly. I've tried different methods and when I changed the joins around and table names it just didn't work properly at all.

Any ideas?

Error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION teams.t_icon does not exist'`

Comment: The `teams` table is not used for any of hte `join` conditions.

Comment: I removed the "teams" prefix but now it says that "league.t_icon" doesn't exist, but I don't have any type of "league" table but "leagues" and the query has no "league" in it either. It doesn't make sense :/

Comment: That's weird, sometimes it says my ON clause is incorrect but it isn't, but sometimes it says my teams.t_icon isn't correct. I don't understand :X

Answer (score 0):

As i see error, you forget `,` after column name. Try this

```
SELECT teams.t_id, teams.t_name, teams.t_icon,
                (COALESCE((SELECT SUM(matches.m_hteam_score) FROM matches WHERE matches.m_tid = teams.t_id), 0) + 
                    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(matches.m_ateam_score) FROM matches WHERE matches.m_tid2 = teams.t_id), 0)
                ) as totalscore           
            FROM teams, matches
                LEFT JOIN divisions ON divisions.d_id = matches.m_did
                AND matches.m_did = divisions.d_id
                LEFT JOIN leagues ON leagues.l_id = divisions.d_lid
            WHERE leagues.l_id = ? AND matches.m_finished = ? AND matches.m_did = ?
```

in your query there is no any relation between teams and matches,devisions,and leagues

Comment: Ahh I did, but it still remains giving me an error.. A different one though, something with my ON clauses. `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'matches.m_did' in 'on clause'' in ` But I know the joins are correct, as I've checked them several times.

Comment: @CameronSwyft you should join divisions.d_id with `teams` table's `column`, in your on clause `divisions.d_id = matches.m_did`, query executor not found `matches` table because you used `matches` table after devisions table

Comment: @CameronSwyft please provide all tables structure I will create query

Comment: These are the right columns for the right tables, I can assure you. It's the COALESCE part witht he query that messes up.. If I remove this then the query works, just doesn't return the totalscore which is what I need.

Comment: Nevermind, the query doesn't work without it now... Man this frusterating, editing topic now... Is there anywhere we can talk privately or no?